# No route matches [POST] in nested routes for form_for helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to submit a form for and keep running into this error:

```
No route matches [POST]
```

here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@issue) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and my routes:

```
  resources :apps do
    resources :issues
  end
```

I think i'm missing something with defining which app it is in the form_for but im not sure?

here's my issue create action:

```
  def create
    @issue = Issue.new(params[:issue])
    @issue.app_id = params[:app_id]
    if @issue.save
      flash[:success] = "Issue added!"
      redirect_to @issue
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put the app in the form as well. Because you have the issues nested in the apps.

```
<%= form_for([@app, @issue]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Because you have your routes like this `apps/:app_id/issues/:issues_id` You need to fetch the @app in your controller.

You can check your available routes with this command: `rake routes`

Comment: ok that worked but now i'm getting a no methoderror when trying to redirect to issue after creating the issue. I added the issue controller action create to the original question, did I do something wrong there?

Comment: something like this, `redirect_to apps_issues_path(@issue.app_id, @issue.id)` Because you nested issues in apps you always need your app when you are doing something with your issue. You can check `rake routes` for all the routes available.

Comment: what would happen if you have such a route?   resources :tasks do   
    collection do
      put :complete
    end      
  end